# My solar inverter display volts but no amps and a few watts. What's wrong?

Tags: solar-power

I have 150watts 7 solar panels of specs : max DC volts 20; max SC amps 8.02Amps.

Individually checked all 7 solar panels short circuit amps and they are in 6.54 - 7.84amps range.

### Solar Inverter Specs

[image: Specification]

### PV Watts in inverter

[image: Watts]

### PV Amps in inverter

[image: Amps]

### PV Volts in inverter

[image: Volts]

Comment: Total square footage/meterage of the solar panels is how much? They's *each* need to be over a square meter/yard to give 150W each, does that fit?

Comment: Hello, the most left label is "PV" under input. All panels are connected in series circuit.
Don't have any circuit diagram.

Comment: Solar Panels Specs:
Rated Maximum Power 150W,
Maximum Power Voltage 20v,Maximum Power Current 8.02A

Comment: To confirm, you've got 7x20V panels in series = 140V nominal (137V measured?), and an inverter input rating of 24V (presumably ideal/minimum)?  Is that within spec?

Comment: Without a complete wiring diagram (including batteries, if you have any) it will be difficult to troubleshoot this for you. We need to know what *should* be happening, in order to figure out why it isn't. Feel free to draw one on paper and include a photo of it.

Comment: @ChrisH it *looks* like the inverter is combined with an MPPT charger... so the charger section takes 120 to 450 VDC and supplies 27VDC max to an inverter section with 24 VDC nominal input. But hard to say from the info here.

Comment: @LShaver that would seem reasonable, though the rating plate appears to give undue prominence to the specifications in between the two parts of one unit - not very clear, and without more info from the OP we're not likely to get far.

Comment: What is the load connected to the system? The inverter will only draw as many watts as there are watts of load to supply.